# Find files, that do not exist in other directory

Tags: files

I need to find all the files, that exist anywhere in `dir1`, but don't exist anywhere in `dir2`. `dir1` and `dir2` may have different structure, so `diff -r` doesn't work well.

Comment: Are you primarily concerned about filenames being the same, or file contents? Would `fdupes` be a first step?

Comment: File names are probably the same, but that's not guaranteed. I meant, that a file exists in other directory, if there exists a file with the same content. I don't know, how can I use `fdupes` for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a list of files without path. In that way, you can compare two directories. However, filenames should all be different. If you have the same filename repeated in dir1 over different subdirectories, removing path will remove uniqueness of the filename. You can get a list of each directory without pathnames like this:

```
find dir1/ -exec basename {} \; | sort
find dir2/ -exec basename {} \; | sort
```

All together would look something like this

```
diff <(find dir1/ -exec basename {} \; | sort) <(find dir2/ -exec basename {} \; | sort)
```

**I see there is a comment suggesting using fdupes. `fdupes` if definitely a better solution.**

Answer (score 0):

A crude method could be using `md5sum`. Only be aware that files with zero length will always be seen as duplicates, so you might want to `find` only files with at least one byte size.

```
find /first/path -type f -exec md5sum -b \{\} \; > /tmp/md5-path1.txt
cut -b1-32 < /tmp/md5-path1-short.txt
find /second/path -type f -exec md5sum -b \{\} \; > /tmp/md5-path2.txt
cut -b1-32 < /tmp/md5-path2-short.txt
```

Files in path1 that are not in path2 (remove the '-v' option

```
grep /tmp/md5-path1.txt -v -F -f /tmp/md5/path2-short.txt
```

**CYA level: professional**

The 32 above is because MD5 hashes are 32 bytes long. If you used, say, `sha1sum`, which has an even smaller chance of collisions, then you would use a length of 40; `sha224sum` requires 56, `sha256sum` requires 64, and `sha512sum` 128.

**CYA level: paranoid**

This might not work in some caching schemes in which metadata are kept in files *whose name contain the hash of the original file*.

(this actually happened to me with a Wordpress + Magento installation years ago, where we wanted to migrate a huge article cache while removing obsolete entries).

In this case you would have to use a different hashing scheme - quick fix - to avoid `grep` returning false positives, mistaking the metadata entry for the original file (so, use SHA1 if the cache uses MD5 or vice versa); or using `sed` to rewrite all lines in the "short" files to add a "^" at the beginning, thus making it into an anchored regex, and removing the `-F` flag from `grep` to process the file as regexes instead of plain strings.

Answer (score 0):

So, the partial solution I found is:

```
find dir1 -type f | grep -vxFf <(fdupes -r dir1 dir2)
```

but I say "partial", because if there are duplicates in `dir1`, they will not be shown, so you need to run `fdupes -r dir1` at first.